# Linq to SQL: Many to Many support class

Tags: linq-to-sql, generics, many-to-many, generic-list

I'd like to have a support class to help with the Many to Many relationship.

As I see it now it could be a double generic class you would define in one or both of the entity partial classes surrounding the relationship.

Getting it to allow access to the other table without having to specifically mention the relationship table should be easy. However adding or removing from the collection is somewhat trickier. You would ahve to add a row into the relationship table aswell and commit it or remove it based on what is done.

Could this be done through a function that is passed into this generic class?

Does a class like this exists and if not is it something that can be viably done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `IManyToManySet<TEntity>` interface that can be returned from your many to many property and have a `ManyToManySet<TSource, TCross, TDestination>` implementation with the query insert and delete features.

The interface may look like this:

```
public interface IManyToManySet<TEntity> : IEnumerable<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    int Count { get; }
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    bool Remove(TEntity entity);
    void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> collection);
}
```

And the implementation might look like this:

```
public class ManyToManySet<TSource, TCross, TDestination>
    : IManyToManySet<TDestination>, IEnumerable<TDestination>
    where TDestination : class
    where TSource : class
    where TCross : class
{
    private TSource source;
    private EntitySet<TCross> crossSet;
    private Func<TCross, TDestination> destinationSelector;
    private Func<TSource, TDestination, TCross> crossFactory;

    public ManyToManySet(TSource source, 
        EntitySet<TCross> crossSet,
        Func<TCross, TDestination> destinationSelector,
        Func<TSource, TDestination, TCross> crossFactory)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.crossSet = crossSet;
        this.destinationSelector = destinationSelector;
        this.crossFactory = crossFactory;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.crossSet.Count; }
    }

    public void Add(TDestination entity)
    {
        var newEntity = this.crossFactory(this.source, entity);
        this.crossSet.Add(newEntity);
    }

    public bool Remove(TDestination entity)
    {
        var existingEntity = (
            from c in this.crossSet
            where this.destinationSelector(c) == entity
            select c)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (existingEntity != null)
        {
            return this.crossSet.Remove(existingEntity);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TDestination> collection)
    {
        foreach (var entity in collection)
        {
            this.Add(entity);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<TDestination> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.crossSet.Select(this.destinationSelector)
            .GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

You need to supply a couple of things in this implementation:

1. The `TSource` instance, that points back at the entity that defines the property.
2. The `EntitySet<TCross>` that points to the list of entities that define the cross table.
3. A projection function that allows you to convert a `TCross` to the `TDestination`.
4. A factory function that allows you to create a new `TCross` based on the `TSource` and `TDestination`.

Translating this to a practical example (Using `Product` and `Order`), would give you the following property in the `Order` entity:

```
private IManyToManySet<Product> products;
public IManyToManySet<Product> Products
{
    get
    {
        if (this.products != null)
        {
            this.products = new ManyToManySet<Order, OrderProduct, Product>(
                this, this.OrderProducts, op => op.Product,
                (o, p) => new OrderProduct { Order = o, Product = p });
        }

        return this.products;
    }
}
```

And the following property in the `Product` entity:

```
private IManyToManySet<Order> orders;
public IManyToManySet<Order> Orders
{
    get
    {
        if (this.orders == null)
        {
            this.orders = new ManyToManySet<Product, OrderProduct, Order>(
                this, this.OrderProducts, op => op.Order,
                (p, o) => new OrderProduct { Order = o, Product = p });
        }

        return this.orders;
    }
}
```

The `IManyToManySet<T>` interface is in fact redundant, because you can return a `ManyToMany<TSource, TCross, TDestination>` directly. The interface however hides the `TSource` and `TCross` type arguments, which makes it a bit more readable to the user of this property.

Note that this implementation has the same loading behavior as LINQ to SQL's `EntitySet<T>`; When it is used, it loads the complete set of objects in memory. Just as with an `EntitySet<T>` using a `where` or `First` on the collection, still loads the complete collection from the database. You need to be aware of that.

Important difference is however that LINQ to SQL understands `EntitySet<T>` properties within LINQ queries. Having a `IManyToManySet<T>` inside a LINQ query will fail miserably.

I hope this helps.

Comment: One thing that I had slight problem with was removing the relation as that action tried to null the Foreign Key in the cross table instead of just removing the row. I found out I could set a DeleteOnNull on the association that ensures the row will be deleted when removed from the parent items entitySet.

Comment: I love it when a plan comes together!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard (perhaps even impossible) to create a solution in LINQ to SQL that feels like something native, because such a solution must work in the following ways:

1. The many collection should be modeled as a property on the other many entity.
2. It must support inserts, updates and deletes.
3. It should work when writing LINQ queries.

It is easy to make a solution for point 1. Take for instance a model with a `Product` class with a many-to-many relationship with `Order`. You could define the following property on the `Order` class:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> Products
{
    get { return this.OrderProducts.Select(op => op.Product); }
}
```

This however doesn't work with point 2 and 3. While we could make a generic collection that allows inserting, LINQ to SQL will never be able to translate the use of this property back into a SQL query. For instance, the following LINQ query looks innocent:

```
var bigOrders =
    from order in context.Orders
    where order.Products.Any(p => p.Price > 100)
    select order;
```

Unfortunately, this query will fail, because LINQ to SQL doesn't know how to map the `Products` property to SQL.

When you want this feature natively, you should consider migrating to Entity Framework (4.0 or up). EF supports this natively.

Comment: Ok I'm going to use EF in my next project. But let's say I wan't the other one in a limited way. Basicly get a list of objects on the other side of the relation (products in your example) and being able to insert, update and delete straight to that collection which would automatically create the relation. Could that be done by passing in functions from the Order class into a custom collection class that handles adding and such?

Comment: @Ingó: See my second answer. I wrote an implementation of a generic class that can do this.